# Change indexer frequency in Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I've created an Index with azure search and made it cusom to run every 5 minute. I did this using the portal and it's based on a sql db. I'm would like to change the indexing frequency, but can't find any way to do this using the portal, is it hidden somewhere? or is the API the only way forward

Best regards

Comment: I am not sure if there is a method to update that parameter. but I guess you can write a function app to trigger index update every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You can update indexer schedule in the portal - on the main search service page, click on indexers tile to get to the indexer properties, then click Edit.